# Return the number of key: value pairs in a Custom Object in Power Automate Desktop

Tags: power-automate, power-automate-desktop

I have JSON that I converted to a custom object.

The JSON:

```
{
"customerId":"cust3456",
"orderId":"or_4567",
"numItems":8
}
```

I've converted it to a custom object named, `varsObject`.

I want to return the number of fields in the custom object. I can reference the fields (keys) and return the values but want the count. There is no length property and `%Count(['varsObject'])%` returns 1 - ie: 1 object?

Thanks.

Comment: For a list you can get the count property like so: `%ListVariableName.Count%` (and a data table has the `RowsCount` property) … not sure whether a custom object has this property as well (although you mentioned about missing length property)